# Modelsim not compiling VHDL code

Tags: vhdl

Wrote my first VHDL code and when compiling Modelsim generated these errors

> Error: E:\Digital Logic\ModelSim\myxor.vhd(10): No feasible entries for prefix operator "xor".
>   ** Error: E:\Digital Logic\ModelSim\myxor.vhd(10): Type error resolving prefix expression "xor" as type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC.
>   ** Error: E:\Digital Logic\ModelSim\myxor.vhd(11): VHDL Compiler exiting

I don't understand why it couldn't resolve xor. xor is defined in the ieee library. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity xorgate is
    port (a : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
          y : out std_logic);
end;

architecture synth of xorgate is
begin
    y <= xor a;
end;
```

Comment: Library IEEE, package std_logic_1164 contains operator overload functions for std_logic_vector. In IEEE Std 1076-2008std_logic_1164 is extended to include a unary xor operator with the signature [std_ulogic_vector return std_ulogic]. That overload operator is not available prior. And this tells us you are missing an option to invoke 2008 VHDL. You could also determine whether or not your synthesis tool supports the unary xor.

Comment: Thank you. Compiler was set to 2002. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by [user1155120](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155120/user1155120), you must work in VHDL 2008 to use the unary `xor`. The `-2008` option of the `vcom` compiler of Modelsim puts you in 2008 mode. For synthesis, look at the documentation of your tool but be aware that a lot of them do not fully support 2008 yet.

In case you need this unary `xor` but cannot work in 2008 mode, you can define a `xor_reduce` function yourself:

```
function xor_reduce(v: std_logic_vector) return std_logic is
    constant n: natural := v'length;
    constant t: std_logic_vector(n - 1 downto 0) := v;
begin
    if n = 0 then
        return '0';
    elsif n = 1 then
        return t(0);
    else
        return xor_reduce(t(n - 1 downto n / 2)) xor xor_reduce(t(n / 2 - 1 downto 0));
    end if;
end function xor_reduce;
```

and use it with the syntax of function calls instead of that of operators:

```
y <= xor_reduce(a);
```

Note: there are simpler and more natural ways to describe this, using a `for` loop, for instance. The recursive style shown above has two interesting properties:

- It illustrates recursion, which is sometimes the most elegant way to describe an operation and is perfectly synthesizable by decently recent synthesizers.
- The binary tree structure it describes is more efficient than a linear one because it leads to worst case propagation delays in `log(n)` instead of `n` where `n` is the input's length. In case your synthesizer is not smart enough to infer a tree structure from a linear description, this will help it a bit.

Comment: I'd generally trust your 'decently recent synthesizers' to be able to flatten (parallelize) the XORs in a loop statement to match any other representation.  There's also `use ieee.numeric_std.all;... y <=  "mod"(unsigned(a), 2)(0);` without writing any additional code, and also synthesizes to the same result. The function call equivalent of the mod operator is used to allow an indexed name from the result which is an unsigned that happens to have a right index of 0.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. Modelsim compiler was set to 2002. CHanged it to 2008 and it compiled.  Thank you!!

Comment: @user1155120: the xor reduction of `a` tells you whether its binary representation comprises an odd or even number of ones, that is, its parity. `"mod"(unsigned(a), 2)(0)` tells you whether `a`, considered as an unsigned integer, is odd or even. It's completely different. And, by the way, `a(a'right)` does the same.

Comment: Now why on earth would I have confused mod with hamming weight?

Answer (score 0):

you should use a1,a2,a3,a4  and then you should use,.. y = a1 xor a2 xor a3 xor a4.
you can not use ... y <= xor a ....  it is wrong declaration.